# Change TLS version ciphers used by Jupyter notebook

Tags: ssl, https, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Since some days ago, my MacOs/Safari client has stopped being able to access my Jupyter Notebook (placed in another server) over HTTPS.

One of the possibilities I am investigating is that Apple may have stopped accepting TLS1.0 cipher algorithms https://www.macrumors.com/2018/10/15/apple-ending-tls-1-1-1-0-support-march-2020/

When I connect to the same Jupyter server from MacOs/Firefox things DO work, but Firefox complains that I am using an insecure ciphering algorithm: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS1.0

I have confirmed "openssl ciphers -v" that my server's box accepts lots of algorithms up to TLS v1.2

How can I instruct Jupyter notebook server to use a higher version protocol?

I can see in Jupiter_notebook_config.py a section that might help:

```
## Supply SSL options for the tornado HTTPServer. See the tornado docs for
#  details.
#c.NotebookApp.ssl_options = {}
```

What should I put here as ssl_options???

Answer (score 5):

I can answer myself

```
c.NotebookApp.ssl_options={
        "ssl_version": ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
    }
```

Solved the problem.

Comment: You may need to add `import ssl` to the file.

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me was:

```
import ssl
c.NotebookApp.ssl_options = {
'ssl_version': ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
}
```

When I got back to call the jupyter notebook, it enabled the tls 1.2 and browser didn't argue about it with a valid let'sencrypt cert